# Spring error creating bean xStreamMarshaller

Tags: java, spring, maven, xstream

I have a problem with starting my Application.

When I start *mvn jetty:run*, I get the following **exception**:

```
2013-08-21 12:14:59.977:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context 
o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/Users/markus/Documents/workspace/shadowrunV3_gui/src/main/webapp/},file:/Users/markus/Documents/workspace/shadowrunV3_gui/src/main/webapp/
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter#3744cc2c' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter] while setting bean property 'messageConverters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter#3744cc2c' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'xStreamMarshaller' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xStreamMarshaller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars]
```

**my applicationContext.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jndi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi/spring-jndi-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <ref bean="xStreamMarshaller" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="xStreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars</value>
            <!-- other classes (the package is correct) -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

    <!-- from an old configuration, from my understanding I dont need this part anymore, but since I'm not sure here it is: -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>
                    at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars
                </value>
                <!-- other classes -->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${hibernate.dialect}
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**my DChars class:**

```
package at.itn.shadowrun.domain;

@Entity
@Table(name = "D_CHARS")
@XStreamAlias("DChars")
public class DChars implements DomainObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long                id;
// etc..
```

And just to make sure I didn't do something wrong in the pom, here's the **spring relevant pom**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Spring version is: *3.2.3.RELEASE*

From my understanding the Class `at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars` cannot be found, but I don't understand why. It's definitely in the correct package!

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank You!

edit: I changed the `@XStreamAlias("DChars")` (the db class is called `D_CHARS`, but in the applicationContext I refer to it as `DChars`. But unfortunately it didnt help

edit2: since I cant figure out what the problem is and want to make sure I didn't overlook a critical mistake in **my applicationContext.xml** I'll add the full file here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jndi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jndi/spring-jndi.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="at.itn.shadowrun.gui.service." />

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/application.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
            <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <ref bean="xStreamMarshaller" />
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xStreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <props>
                <prop key="DChars">at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wicketApplication" class="at.itn.shadowrun.ShadowrunApplication">
    </bean>

    <!-- tells Spring to put transactional advice on any class or method that 
        has an @Transactional annotation on it -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    </beans>
```

I still don't get the problem, because the File `DChars` is definately in the `at.itn.shadowrun.domain`package. If anyone has any idea help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change xStreamMarshaller as follow :

```
   <bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <props>
            <prop key="D_CHARS">at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

and make sure you have corresponding bean in app context for DChars class.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately the problem seems to be the same:

`Property 'aliases' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars`

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "make sure you have corresponding bean in app context for DChars class."?

I have placed the DChars class in the package `at.itn.shadowrun.domain` and set the prop key like you did in your example code (I also tried the `key="DChars"` since I renamed the `@XStreamAlias`in the DChars class

Comment: Try adding <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/> to xstreamMarshaller bean.Also, in my case I have added bean in appcontext for Domain object.For example in your case  : <bean id="DChars" class="at.itn.shadowrun.domain.DChars"/>  in appContext.xml.